# What's the difference between metonymy, meronymy, meronomy and mereology?

Tags: terminology, lexical-semantics, logic, lexical-relations

I know that these terms are used in different subfields of linguistics:

- [Metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) and metonyms are used in rhetorics and metaphor theory.
- [Meronymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meronymy) and meronyms are used in lexical semantics.
- [Meronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meronomy), [mereology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mereology) and merons have to do with logic, ontologies and natural language processing.

They are related in names and meaning, so I hope somebody can explicitly contrast them with each other and describe their relations. Is mereology a study of meronomies, which are hierarchies of merons connected by the relation of meronymy? Are meronyms used as metonyms?

Comment: Can you explain more what you don't understand? There isn't really any commonality between metonym and meronym/meronomy. And meronomy is also used in regular semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to understanding is the difference between objects and names of objects: 
A meronom is a part. 
A meronym is the name of a part. 
A meronomy is a relationship between parts and sub-parts. 
Meronymy is a relationship between words.

Mereology is the mathematical study of parts and wholes. It cares about mathematical objects, not about words. The kind of mathematical structure mereology studies is a relation called a meronomy.

Why not 'mereonomy'? You do see that sometimes. But 'meronomy' is more common, and more correct, albeit also more obnoxious. You see, someone was being clever: 'Meronomy' is a back-formation from 'taxonomy'. Taxonomy is based on subsumption, rather than composition. Taxonomy is in turn the basis for set theory. Set theory and mereology are alternative ways to formulate a universal foundation for mathematics. If you're a programmer, you can think of them as the difference between relational data structures and object-oriented data structures. (If you're not a programmer, you're on your own.)

Finally, a metonym is a figure of speech that substitutes one word or phrase for another. This is superficially unrelated to meronymy and meronomy. But if a metonym happens to involve substituting a meronym for a holonym, then you have a kind of metonymy called synecdoche. Actually, though, I think the Wikipedia entries on these other terms include "Not to be confused with metonymy" based on the similar spellings, rather than this somewhat tortured connection. ;-)